# Set an equal size of two boxes with relative unit (em)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm reacquanting about CSS stuff.  I'm tackling the code over there. I can't understand how the dimensions of h1 and section boxes are set. The dimension is the same but in h1 tag I have max-width=15em and in the .chapter class max-width=36em. Both the elements are children of body and thus em that is relative to its own parent (the body that has 16px by default ) should be respectively of 240px(15x16) and  576(36x16) instead the two boxes have the same dimension. Where am I wrong? Can someone explain me why the two boxes have the same dimension?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pseudo elements</title>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      max-width: 15em;
      margin: 1em auto .5em;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: 3em;
      padding-bottom: .5em;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    }

    .chapter {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 36em;
      padding-left: 10em;
      position: relative;
    }

    .chapter p {
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    }
    
    .chapter::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      content: '”';
      font-size: 20em;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: -0.1em;
      color: #ccc;
      speak: none;
    }
        /**
        * Create a "drop-cap" by floating the first letter.
        */
        .chapter p::first-letter {
          float: left;
          font-size: 3em;
          line-height: 0.8;
          margin-top: .15em;
          margin-right: .1em;
          font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
        }
        /** 
        * Support note: at the time of writing, Google Chrome (and possibly 
        * other Blink/Chromium-based browsers) *still* don’t support the 
        * text-transform property within the ::first-line pseudo-element,
        * for some inexplicable reason.
        */
        .chapter p::first-line {
          font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
          text-transform: uppercase;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>A Study In Scarlet</h1>
      <section class="chapter">
        <p>In the year 1878 I took my degree of Doctor of Medicine of the University of London, and proceeded to Netley to go through the course prescribed for surgeons in the army. Having completed my studies there, I was duly attached to the Fifth Northumberland Fusiliers as Assistant Surgeon.</p>
      </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty about CSS.  em is a dimension relative to element itself (not to its own parent except if there isn't the font-size dimension in that element). In this case the font-size dimension for h1 is 3em consequently size box= 16x3x15=720px
For the .chapter I have 36em=36x16=576  + padding 10em=160px    576+160=736 less or more the same dimension.